# When I say data.dtypes == np.object, where data is the dataset I am working on. What does this expression mean?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, object, machine-learning

Well, I am very new to programming. I have been trying my hands around numpy in python. In this case I have a csv file that I have assigned into the variable. I have checked the shape of the variable and I also see the dtypes of the values in the dataset. But my documentation reads the entry in the question I asked about, where it tries to equate the data.dtypes to np.object. I don't quite understand what does it mean. But when I did execute it on the python console I got the below output.

column1         False
column2         False
column3        False
column4           True
.....

Appreciate if someone could explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`np.object` - is a dtype that is used for strings and non-scalar values in cells.

Demo:

CSV file:

```
col1,col2,col3
1,2,3
4,XXX,6

data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

result:

```
In [84]: data
Out[84]:
   col1 col2  col3
0     1    2     3
1     4  XXX     6

In [85]: data.dtypes
Out[85]:
col1     int64
col2    object
col3     int64
dtype: object

In [86]: data.dtypes == np.object
Out[86]:
col1    False
col2     True
col3    False
dtype: bool
```

now let's add a column with non-scalar values (lists):

```
In [87]: data['col4'] = [[1,2], [3,4,5]]

In [88]: data
Out[88]:
   col1 col2  col3       col4
0     1    2     3     [1, 2]
1     4  XXX     6  [3, 4, 5]

In [89]: data.dtypes
Out[89]:
col1     int64
col2    object
col3     int64
col4    object
dtype: object

In [90]: data.dtypes == np.object
Out[90]:
col1    False
col2     True
col3    False
col4     True
dtype: bool
```

Comment: Very well explained indeed!. Thank you for the example. So does it mean when you say it is used for strings and non-scalar values. In this case I see col2 is an int64 and was considered false. So does it mean that anything that is not an object will be considered False when we equate data.dtypes to np.object?  .. Well I am trying to build a purpose for using this in my mind. So when I have a data set in hand, I know where exactly to apply this.

Comment: Perfect!. I think I understand it much better now. Very helpful explaination.

Comment: @Sudhi, glad I could help :)